# Captcha doesn't work for my site

Tags: captcha

I'm using Drupal for my site, and I activated the CAPTCHA image for the login of the administration user. However, it doesn't work.

I don't see the CAPTCHA image, which is replaced by a placeholder.

> [image: screenshot]

Why does this happen? Do I need to fix something in the settings?

May you tell me how I can, at least, skip this verification to be able to log in, and remove the CAPTCHA for my account?

Comment: If you could skip the verfication, it wouldn't be very useful, would it? :) More often than not this is caused by the web server not having correct file permissions, I.e. It can't write to the public files folder. that would be a good place to start, if only to rule it out. If it's an option for you, `drush uli` will give you a one time login link that shouldn't be captcha protected

Comment: In cases like this, it is oftentimes diagnostic to know what errors can be seen in the browser's web console.

Comment: @Clive If I can skip the captcha it will be a great thing sure ... I'm seeing how to install drush correctly because it doesnt work properly actually !

Comment: @cliefen : the link = http://defitabac.ca/user .. you can see the console

Comment: @Clive, Ok I got a code when executing drush uli, but how to use it to login into my admin page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because the PHP GD Library was not installed in my machine...  So I installed the GD Library using `sudo yum install php56w-gd` and the things working good actually.

Note that to access to admin page (my aim) we can deactivate the captcha module using  this command : `drush dis captcha`

Comment: It's not a answer to your original question, however I am glad you found a alternative solution.